# MVC Contrib PassParametersDuringRedirect - stop values persisting past first redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

New to MVcContrib so maybe I am using it incorrectly, but I am having a problem using the PassParametersDuringRedirect attribute.

The problem I am having is that, as expected, parameter values are passed correctly when I first redirect, the problem is that after this the values are still persiting, whereas if I use TempData (which I don't want to do), then the values only persist for the first call.

Code is below. When I populate model.ErrorMessage and then redirect to Shelf, things work as expected, however all subsequent calls to Shelf still have the ErrorMessage populated.

[PassParametersDuringRedirect]
    public class NewCapitalStructureController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IShelfService shelfService;

```
    public NewCapitalStructureController(IRepository repository, IPrincipalProxy principal, IShelfService shelfService)
        : base(repository, principal)
    {
        this.shelfService = shelfService;
    }

    public ActionResult Shelf(NewCapitalStructureViewModel model)
    {

        if (model == null)
            model = new NewCapitalStructureViewModel();
        return View("Shelf", model);
    }

    public ActionResult SaveShelf(NewCapitalStructureViewModel newCapitalStructureViewModel)
    {
        var result = shelfService.CreateShelf(newCapitalStructureViewModel.ShelfName);
        var model = new NewCapitalStructureViewModel();
        model.ShelfID = result.ID;
        if (!result.Success)
            model.ErrorMessage = result.Message;
        return this.RedirectToAction(x=> x.Shelf(model));
    }
```

Comment: We just started using this attribute as well and noticed the same issue.  Looking in the Source Code of the PassParamtersDuringRedirectAttribute.cs: `filterContext.Controller.TempData.Keep(storedParameter.Key);`

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult Shelf(NewCapitalStructureViewModel model)
{
    if (model == null)             
        model = new NewCapitalStructureViewModel(); 
    ControllerContext.Controller.TempData.Clear();      
    return View("Shelf", model);
}
```

This would clear all the parameter in TempData.

Answer (score 0):

To get around this, I created a new attribute (again inheriting from `ActionFilterAttribute`) and decorated the Shelf method above with the new attribute:

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    filterContext.Controller.TempData.Clear();
}
```

Would love to know if I am going wrong here somewhere though.